# Android App Update Getting Rejected for Keyword Spam

Tags: android, google-play, android-update-app

I published an Android app called "Never Have I Ever". The app was and still is live on Google Play. I updated the app once. Then the second time I tried to update the APK file, I was emailed a messaging saying that my app has been rejected for keyword spam. I updated my app 10 more times changing my app description to the bare minimum. I tried contacting Google Play. Yesterday I tried to update my app title from "Never Have I Ever" to "The Never Have I Ever Game" hoping that maybe it will finally be fixed. No, I was finally contacted by Google Play saying that my app was reviewed and that my app title matched another app "Never Have I Ever Game". Now, this is ridiculous to me. How is it that Google didn't see my other 10 updates, but only saw this last one? How is it my app "Never Have I Ever" was fine until, one day it got rejected? There are so many apps with the name "Never Have I Ever" on Google Play. I have an app "Truth or Dare" that never got rejected for having the name "Truth or Dare". Basically, I am frustrated that I have not been given any answers by Google, and that my title and description is definitely not worth of rejection. Maybe I am wrong, but would definitely need an answer.

> Your app submission has been rejected for a violation of the Google Play Developer Programme Policy regarding Impersonation or Deceptive Behaviour. Please review the keyword spam policy help article, then modify your app's title and/or description and resubmit. Additional details have been sent to your account owner's email address.

Title: Never Have I Ever

Short Description: A fun way to party or drink!

Description: Enjoy the game with a group by using the application for questions. The app counts the number of people that have done the particular statement asked. When you are playing, simply swipe from right to left in order to go to the next question. Alternatively, swipe left to right in order to go to the home screen or simply press the back button. I hope you enjoy the game.

Why is the above information being rejected? I even tried again to change the title, this time to "Adult Never Have I Ever" and still getting rejected.

Comment: Buddy, you are not alone. Even I had faced rejections of one of my app. Earlier it's name used to be "Linux Guide" but they rejected because there are many other apps with same name, so I renamed it to "Guide to Linux" and it worked in my case.

Comment: So my app finally is not rejected anymore. Still it does not make sense. I pressed update again without changing the information, and the app went through.